# Auto Renewal -In App Purchase Upgrade if we have website and app for the same Domain

Tags: android, ios, paypal, in-app-purchase, subscriptions

I need suggestion to manage the auto renewal subscriptions , if we have iOS ,Android and website, how the upgrade, downgrade works in Sync.

need to know, if i buy a subscriptions through iOS, and than switch to android and upgrade from Android or web, how it will work